# Command is executable in terminal that I opened, but cannot execute when I use java function to open terminal and execute it

Tags: java, shell, command-line

I am trying to write a java program that can open terminal and input a command to it. The command is "wrspice" which can start an application. I have added "wrspice" PATH in .bashrc and it works fine. But when I write a java code using ProcessBuilder to execute, it pop up "bash: wrspice: command not found" error. Here is my java code:

```
final String[] wrappedCommand;
wrappedCommand = new String[]{ "xterm", "-hold", "-e", "wrspice"};
Process process = new 
ProcessBuilder(wrappedCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```

This code works fine when I replace "wrspice" with "ls" to print the file list. But when I try "wrspice" it gives me error for "command not found".

Here is how I add "wrspice" in .bashrc:
    export PATH=/usr/local/xictools/bin:$PATH

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't an interactive shell. Specify the full-path to your command instead. And you don't need `new String[]`. Like,

```
wrappedCommand = { "xterm", "-hold", "-e", "/usr/local/xictools/bin/wrspice"};
```

You should probably specify the path to xterm as well. Double check on your system.

```
wrappedCommand = { "/usr/bin/xterm", "-hold", "-e", "/usr/local/xictools/bin/wrspice"};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Elliott! That works and I have tried different commands like "conda" and "jsim". Seems like you need to use specific path to the non-system commands.